# verses of guidance for family harmony and health?

Tags: children, family

I am looking for verses of guidance for family life and harmony, love of wife and nurturing children, how to discipline, kindness, education, young adulthood.

Comment: there are many verses regarding family. the answer will be too long. better to go to [this website](https://al-islam.org/) and look for some books.